# How can I determine what each object in an ArrayList is?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that contains both Foos and Bars.
How can I iterate through this ArrayList determining whether each item is a Foo or a Bar?
I thought it would be as simple as my below attempt, but I get a warning that Foo and Bar are types and cannot be used as expressions.

```
Dim myArrayList As New ArrayList
Dim foo As New Foo
Dim bar As New Bar

myArrayList.add(foo)
myArrayList.add(bar)

For counter As Integer = 0 To myArrayList.Count
    If myArrayList.Item(counter).GetType() = Foo Then
        Response.Write("Item " & counter & " is a Foo")
    Else
        Response.Write("Item " & counter & " is a Bar")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: you need `GetType(Foo)` in order to compare Type to Type; although `foo As New Foo` is kind of wonky since VB is not case sensitive

Comment: Take a look at the ['is' keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

Comment: An ArrayList is a legacy collection that you really should abandon in favor of the generic List - 2 lists: List(Of Foo) and List(Of Bar).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
If TypeOf myArrayList.Item(counter) Is Foo Then
    Response.Write("Item " & counter & " is a Foo")
Else
    Response.Write("Item " & counter & " is a Bar")
End If
```